# Can I use a #id_or_nameid after a rewritten url?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, anchor

my application uses mod_rewrite to make good looking urls.

in my app, a business would be located at

http://my.site.com/region/country/city/business/businessname

Can I add this:

http://my.site.com/region/country/city/business/businessname#nameid

to go directly to an anchor on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add this http://my.site.com/region/country/city/business/businessname#nameid to go directly on an anchor.

I think in this page (http://my.site.com/region/country/city/business/businessname) there must have anchor the